Node Server running on a Synology NAS
I bought a NAS that I setup as a webdev server, among other things. I am having trouble accessing a node server via dynamic domain, but I can access it via local IP (the NAS' IP on my network). I can access a PHP server on it via dynamic domain. This leads my to believe I have something wrong in my DSM setup, but I am not sure what.
When I create a Web Service for node, it builds fine, but it's status switched from Normal to Abnormal. I noticed it creating a container, it has an error as a status. I posted the error below.
requireStack: []  
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:36:49 {
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:170:5)
at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:216:24)
at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:322:14)
at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:27)
at Function._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1246:15)
Error: Cannot find module '/home/node/server.js'

Frustratingly, I can still access the server while the container has an error state.
I don't know enough node to understand the error, but this line 'Error: Cannot find module '/home/node/server.js' leads me to believe there is a problem with where the project files are stored.
Once the container status is good, I assume I make a Web Portal for it back in Web Station.
Any help would be appretiated. TIA
